# How do I make a input field active after I tick a checkbox, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-input

I have this code I wrote but it doesnt seem to be working, see below:

```
$('#Reserve, #BuyItNowPrice, #featureplate').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('.fake-fieldset .fake-input').css({'background-color':'#e1e1e1'});

$('.enable').click(function(){

    if($('.enable:checked')){
        $(this).closest('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
        $(this).closest('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

This HTML structure is repeated 3 times in my code, see below

```
   <strong><input type="checkbox" class="enable" /> Specify Buy It Now Price</strong>
   <div class="fake-fieldset">
     <div class="fake-input">
       <span>&pound;&nbsp;</span>
         <input type="text" id="BuyItNowPrice" name="BuyItNowPrice" value="" />
     </div>
   </div>
```

What I'd like to happen is when I check `.enable` the closest input should become active so the user can type a value

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to change: I don't think you can do

```
if($('.enable:checked'))
```

as a selector always returns a jQuery object (rather than true or false); instead try

```
if($('.enable).is(:checked'))
```

Second, since `closest` is looking for an ancestor, you need a better way to connect the checkbox with the related `input`; maybe put them both into a wrapper div?  Then you can go up to the parent (the wrapper) and do a find from there.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks for an ancestor element which the `input` you are trying to change is not.

You probably need to change your HTML a bit to make this work. One suggestion is to create a parent element to wrap both elements and add a class to the 2nd input. Something like this:

```
<div class='enablearea'>
  <strong><input type="checkbox" class="enable" /> Specify Buy It Now Price</strong>
  <div class="fake-fieldset">
    <div class="fake-input">
      <span>&pound;&nbsp;</span>
      <input type="text" id="BuyItNowPrice" name="BuyItNowPrice" value="" class='enablechange' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can find that 2nd input like this:

```
$(this).parent('.enablearea').find('.enablechange')
```